# What is heartbeat in gwt-comet?

Tags: gwt, server-push

I would like to know what is the actual meaning of **heartbeat** and it's usage in [gwt-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like a real heartbeat, they are used to check if something is alive or dead. In the case of gwt-comet, it is the same. Heartbeat is used to ensure a connection to the comet server to/from the server. It is very simple really.